# Is it possible to make a Razor Tag Helper to show/hide content wrapped in it under certain server side conditions

Tags: razor, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

As per the title really, but to give it more specifics:

My web app has multiple users, each has a different set of permissions and this means that certain parts of the app aren't available to them, in most cases this is simple, whole sections are just blocked out and not displayed at all, but in some cases I would like to be able to wrap a certain section of a page in a tag which if the user hasn't permission to see will either hide this section entirely, or show a "you don't have permission to use this bit" partial view.

I am using .NET Core 3.1 and Razor Pages.

So I am thinking something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    My web page content....
    <permission requires="view_invoices">
        <h3>Invoices</h3>
        .... invoice content.... 
        BUT - if user has not got permission this section is skipped, so is blank, or shows (/Views/Partial/PermissionNotAvailable)
    </permission>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit - for clarity, I want to be able to write my content assuming the user has permission to view it, but if they don't, the fact that it is wrapped in the `permissions` tag helper will have it removed or replaced by a server-side helper.

Comment: check this https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2017/11/05/authorize-tag-helper.aspx

Comment: Ohhhh... with some modifications this looks perfect, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [ASP.NET authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/introduction?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and razor pages you can do something like the following:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("ViewInvoices")) {
    <h3>Invoices</h3>
    .... invoice content.... 
} else {
    (/Views/Partial/PermissionNotAvailable)
}
```

Where `ViewInvoices` is a role you added to the database and assigned to certain users. If the user does not have this role that section of the page is not returned to the client.

Comment: Yeah - I can do it with a bunch of C# if/else, but I was looking for something more elegant. The link in the comment on the question above looks just right.